# pointer casting in c [shellcode test]

Tags: c, shellcode

I'm following a tutorial on how to write a shellcode but I'm failing to understand what this pointer function casting is doing to the bytecode, could someone explain this to me?.

```
char code[] = "bytecode will go here!";
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   int (*func)();
   func = (int (*)()) code;
   (int)(*func)();
}
```

the code is something like this "\xb0\x01\x31\xdb\xcd\x80" for exiting it's the result of objdump of an assembly code that exits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code itself has not only undefined behaviour, it is bad wherever it doesn't. Let's go through the lines:

1. Declare func as a pointer to a function returning an int, with no prototype.

   ```
   int (*func)();
   ```
2. cast the array which decays to a pointer to the first character in the array, into a pointer to function returning `int` having no prototype, and assign it to `func`. This of course has totally undefined behaviour.

   ```
   func = (int (*)()) code;
   ```
3. The third line is the worst of them all:

   ```
   (int)(*func)();
   ```

   Here we dereference the function pointer with `*func`, then it immediately decays
   back to a function pointer because it is subjected to the function call operator which only works with *function pointers*! Then the return value, which is an `int`, is cast to an `int`, and then discarded.

Of course the 3rd line should have been written as `func();`. And since the return value is very probably handled via registers, and we're not interested in it, the proto for the shellcode function should have been `void shellcode(void)`. Lastly, you don't need a variable here for the function pointer. Therefore we could just write

```
( (void (*)(void)) code ) ();
```

i.e. cast the `code` as a pointer to function returning `void` taking no arguments, then call it.

Answer (score 0):

You define a function pointer `func` that points to a function which will return an integer.

In the second line, you assign your bytecode to that function pointer, but you have to cast it to a function pointer first, there is no default conversion between a character array and a function pointer.

Lastly, you try to call the function that `func` points to, thereby hoping to execute your bytecode.

Comment: It's worth noting that the las line's syntax is needlessly convoluted, a simple `func();` would be enough.

Comment: thanks!! that clarified a lot of things. it makes sense now ^^

Comment: Note that is not a function pointer that takes no arguments. It takes arbitrary number of arguments! Just try!

Comment: Right, I've removed that line, thank you for the clarification. And yes, the last line is needlessly messy.